# Create callback script for Joomla

Tags: javascript, callback, joomla3.0

An On-Line Assessment has "API Callback Url" which call a web page/script/php file in joomla root to pass information (asynchronously) once student submit a quiz that I need to capture to joomla data base user account.

I need a script to put in this php file to check if the username doesn't exist then create the user (as Registered Group) and add the information. If username exist then just add the information to his account (the key here would be username). Student now can login to Joomla and view test history.

these are the supported variables from the On-Line Assessment:

```
username        :the username of the user, if available.
firstname       :the first name of the user, if available.
lastname        :the last name of the user, if available.
cf_label        :the value of this custom field (for example, cf_company if you have a custom field labelled mpany).
title           :the title of the publication.
accesscode      :the access code entered by the user, if available.
id              :the id of the response.
ispreview       :indicates if it's a preview (1) or a real response (0).
pin             :the PIN of the publication (empty if it's a preview).
score           :the score (points) got by the user.
scorepercent    :the score (percent) got by the user.
startdate       :the date/time (UTC, yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss) when the response was started.
enddate         :the date/time (UTC, yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss) when the response was completed.
status          :the status of the response (2=completed, 3=passed, 4=not passed, 5=to be graded).
gr_label        :the value of this custom grade (for example, gr_passed if you have a custom grade labelled passed).
maxscore        :the maximum score available for the publication.
minscore        :the minimum score available for the publication.
```

They provide a general example with two methods (POST) and (GET):

```
<?php

    // === GET SINGLE PARAMETER (VIA POST) ===
    $accessCode = $_POST["accesscode"];
    $cfCompany = $_POST["cf_company"];

    echo "Access Code: ".$accessCode."<br />";
    echo "Company (Custom Field): ".$cfCompany."<br />";

    // === GET SINGLE PARAMETER (VIA GET) ===
    $pin = $_GET["pin"];
    $grPassed = $_GET["gr_passed"];

    echo "Pin: ".$pin."<br />";
    echo "Grade: ".$grPassed."<br />";

    // === GET ALL PARAMETERS (VIA POST) ===
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        echo htmlspecialchars($key).": ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";

?>
```

could you help creating the script ..
appreciated,

**Update1**:
I got this script from [diadem.in](http://diadem.in/blog/two-ways-to-add-joomla-users-using-your-custom-code/) and put it in html as I understand, however is this correct and how to make it check for username first via post like in the example above!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();


//Check for request forgeries: comment this since tokens are not generated in the html 
//JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );

//Get required system objects
$user         = clone(JFactory::getUser());
$pathway          = & $mainframe->getPathway();
$config       = & JFactory::getConfig();
$authorize        = & JFactory::getACL();
$document       = & JFactory::getDocument();

//Initialize new usertype setting
$newUsertype = $usersConfig->get( 'new_usertype' );
if (!$newUsertype)
{
$newUsertype = 'Registered';
}

//Bind the post array to the user object
if (!$user->bind( JRequest::get('post'), 'usertype' ))
{
JError::raiseError( 500, $user->getError());
}

//Set some initial user values
$user->set('id', 0);
$user->set('usertype', '');
$user->set('gid', $authorize->get_group_id( '', $newUsertype, 'ARO' ));

$date =& JFactory::getDate();
$user->set('registerDate', $date->toMySQL());

//Save the details of the user
$user->save();


</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Update2: I tried this one but no luck ..

```
<?php 

function register_user ($username, $email, $firstname, $lastname, $password){ 

//This is the original code which I comment to get via POST
 //$firstname = $email; // generate $firstname
 //$lastname = ''; // generate $lastname
 //$username = $email; // username is the same as email

// === GET SINGLE PARAMETER (VIA POST) ===
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $password = $_POST["username"];

 /*
 I handle this code as if it is a snippet of a method or function!!
 First set up some variables/objects     */

 // get the ACL
 $acl =& JFactory::getACL();

 /* get the com_user params */
 jimport('joomla.application.component.helper'); // include libraries/application/component/helper.php
 $usersParams = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' ); // load the Params

 // "generate" a new JUser Object
 $user = JFactory::getUser(0); // it's important to set the "0" otherwise your admin user information will be loaded

 $data = array(); // array for all user settings

 // get the default usertype
 $usertype = $usersParams->get( 'new_usertype' );
 if (!$usertype) {
     $usertype = 'Registered';
 }

 // set up the "main" user information
 //original logic of name creation
 //$data['name'] = $firstname.' '.$lastname; // add first- and lastname
 $data['name'] = $firstname.$lastname; // add first- and lastname

 $data['username'] = $username; // add username
 $data['email'] = $email; // add email
 $data['gid'] = $acl->get_group_id( '', $usertype, 'ARO' );  // generate the gid from the usertype

 /* no need to add the usertype, it will be generated automaticaly from the gid */

 $data['password'] = $password; // set the password
 $data['password2'] = $password; // confirm the password
 $data['sendEmail'] = 1; // should the user receive system mails?

 /* Now we can decide, if the user will need an activation */
 $useractivation = $usersParams->get( 'useractivation' ); // in this example, we load the config-setting
 if ($useractivation == 1) { // yeah we want an activation

     jimport('joomla.user.helper'); // include libraries/user/helper.php
     $data['block'] = 1; // block the User
     $data['activation'] =JUtility::getHash( JUserHelper::genRandomPassword() ); // set activation hash (don't forget to send an activation email)

 }
 else { // no we need no activation

     $data['block'] = 1; // don't block the user

 }

 if (!$user->bind($data)) { // now bind the data to the JUser Object, if it not works....

     JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError())); // ...raise an Warning
     return false; // if you're in a method/function return false

 }

 if (!$user->save()) { // if the user is NOT saved...

     JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError())); // ...raise an Warning
     return false; // if you're in a method/function return false

 }

 return $user; // else return the new JUser object

 }

 $email = JRequest::getVar('email');
 $password = JRequest::getVar('password');

 //echo 'User registration...'.'<br/>';
 register_user($email, $password);
 //echo '<br/>'.'User registration is completed'.'<br/>';
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Speak to what you have tried and where you are stuck rather than using your question as a code-writing request.

Comment: Thanks for your participation, I searched and tried many script found here in OS! but still couldn't figure it out.